# When to put parenthesis after a function, following a dot operator?

Tags: python, function

In this piece of code, I get the size of an image and show it. However, when I get the size of it I use a dot operator without the parentheses and when I show the image I use a dot operator and parenthesis. Why? I feel that both of them are functions.

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("arda.jpg")
print(image.size)
image.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot (`.`) signals an *attribute access*. When you do `Image.open` you are saying to python: take the `Image` object and give me the `open` attribute.

Attributes can be *anything*. In this case `open` `show` are *methods*, i.e. they are functional types and so they can be called, while `size` is just a normal value.

Note that you can also do:

```
print(image.show)
```

As you can see even the `show` method is just an attribute like `size`.

---

A complete example:

```
In [1]: class Image:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.size = (1,2)
   ...:     def open(self, name):
   ...:         print('Calling open')
   ...:     def show(self):
   ...:         print('calling show')
   ...:         

In [2]: image = Image()

In [3]: image.open('test')
Calling open

In [4]: image.show()
calling show

In [5]: print(image.size)    #size is just a value, so we don't call it.
(1, 2)

In [6]: print(image.show)    # show is just a (functional) value we *can* call it
<bound method Image.show of <__main__.Image object at 0x7fafacfe8a58>>
```